# UIPickerView reloadAllComponents not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got problems with reload component in UIPickerView. Here is my code:

on my header file (.h):

```
@interface GoToAyatViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerViewObj;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerViewObj;

@end
```

on my implementation (.m):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) { 
        // Custom initialization.
        ratusan = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"      0",@"      1",nil];
        puluhan = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"      0",@"      1",@"      2",
                @"      3",@"      4", @"      5", 
                @"      6", @"      7", @"      8", 
                @"      9",nil];
        satuan = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"      0",@"      1",@"      2",
                  @"      3",@"      4", @"      5", 
                  @"      6", @"      7", @"      8", 
                  @"      9",nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pickerViewObj = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 400, 80)];
    pickerViewObj.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerViewObj.dataSource = self;
    pickerViewObj.delegate = self;  
    [self.pickerViewObj selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [pasalTypeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    self.isPasal = YES;
    self.title = self.kitab;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return kPICKERCOLUMN;
    NSLog(@"numberOfComponentsInPickerView jalan");
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInComponent jalan");
    if (component==0){
        return [ratusan count];
    }else if (component == 1) {
        return [puluhan count];
    }else{
        return [satuan count];
    }

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"set title run");
    switch (component) 
    {
        case 0:
            return [ratusan objectAtIndex:row];
            //break;
        case 1:
            return [puluhan objectAtIndex:row];
            //break;
        case 2:
            return [satuan objectAtIndex:row];
            //break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

and in the implementation i put ibaction to set new value for 1st component on my uipickerview and fire reloadallcomponents:

```
-(IBAction) showAyat
{
self.ratusan = nil;
    self.ratusan = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"      0",@"      1",@"      2",nil];
    [self.pickerViewObj reloadAllComponents];
    NSLog(@"total ratusan=%d", [self.pickerViewObj numberOfRowsInComponent:0]);
}
```

here the picture of my nib setting in case i do wrong in setting delegate or datasource.

[image: xib setting]

by code above when i fire (tap button) showAyat method, it doesnt change the valu of my uipickerview at runtime, but i can see numberOfRowsInComponent:0 has already changed to 3 (before 2) using NSLog. I dont know what is wrong with my pickerview doesnt update the display.
Please someone help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

You are creating two `UIPickerView`.

- One in Xib (connecting as IBOutlet).
- Second in code (inside viewDidLoad: method).

Both get data values from your `delegate`.

Since the picker created in Xib loses connection to the `pickerViewObj` variable when you initialize another second `UIPickerView` in code. So the `UIPickerView` presented at the time doesn't changes its value.

**Solution:**

Remove the code for creating `UIPickerView` from code.

Comment: woo u tottaly rite.., tx alot really save my time